# Using some symbol other than braces for path decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

In tikz, we can do path replacing decoration with braces.

**Is it possible to do this with some other symbol instead?** (eg: square bracket). In the manuals, there is no direct method for this is given. I have a feeling that this is not possible directly. I would like to make sure this.

Note that here i am interested in one long symbol as a path: NOT repeated symbols along a path (as in [Putting repeated symbols along a path with decorations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243628/157031) ).

May be, something like text along path will do; is it so? (if one can 'kind of rotate' the text along a path, that would suffice). But, I suppose that would be hard to do.

Thank you

update: @marmot's answer was an eye-opener. After all, the idea of having a rotated text stretched along a path may not work. I thank @marmot for the effort he put in (i can never do latex code like that :< ). Yet, the stretching of the symbol this way kills it as pointed out by @sebastiano. But, for some symbols there may be better ways to do it. For example, this question for square brackets: [Is there a TikZ equivalent to the PSTricks \ncbar command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55068/157031) as pointed out by @marmot in his answer.

Comment: The answer to the question "Is it possible to use some symbol other than braces for path decoration?" is "Yes, if you are willing to define such a decoration.". A square bracket is almost trivial, other symbols may be more challenging. If you ask a concrete question of the sort "How can one get square brackets instead of braces?", I guess you will get an answer with a code.

Comment: Am I using @ symbol wrong here? If so, please let me know. This one got me confused.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if that is the answer you are looking for but of course you can replace any straight line by a symbol that gets stretched accordingly. (Of course this won't produce nice looking braces or brackets. Nice brackets can be produced with this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55069/121799), and nice braces can be made using `decorations.pathreplacing`, as you pointed out yourself.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{replace path by symbol/.style={to path={%
let
\p1=($(\tikztotarget)-(\tikztostart)$),\n1={veclen(\y1,\x1)},\n2={\n1/width("#1")} 
in \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("#1")}
\typeout{\n1,\n2,\mywidth}}
(\tikztotarget) -- (\tikztostart) node [midway,sloped,xscale=\n2]{#1}
}},
replace path by rotated symbol/.style={to path={%
let
\p1=($(\tikztotarget)-(\tikztostart)$),\n1={veclen(\y1,\x1)},\n2={\n1/height("#1")} 
in \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{width("#1")}
\typeout{\n1,\n2,\mywidth}}
(\tikztotarget) -- (\tikztostart) node [midway,sloped,rotate=90,yscale=\n2]{#1}
}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) coordinate (A) (2,1) coordinate (B) (4,0) coordinate (C) (6,1) coordinate (D);
\path[replace path by symbol=t] (A) to (B);
\path[replace path by rotated symbol={]}] (C) to (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is this? :-) An antenna? You know how much the left image looks like a car wiper blade? :)